# Display function result

Tags: delphi

I'm having a weird problem that is driving me crazy, I is appearing the typical cartel 'could not find program' when I try to run the program, the error is caused when avast is active because when I disable the avast program amiss but when I use it I get this.

The code just do this:

```
program Project1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

var
  pagina1,pagina2: string;

function probando_1(url, parte: string): string;
begin
  if (parte = 'a') then
  begin
    Result := 'test';
  end;
  if (parte = 'b') then
  begin
    Result := 'test';
  end;
end;

begin

  pagina1 := 'http://www.test.com/zzz/test.php';

  try

    WriteLn(probando_1(pagina1, 'a'));
    WriteLn(probando_1(pagina1, 'b'));

     readln;

  except
    on E: Exception do
      WriteLn(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;

end.
```

You see it is not complicated and that's the worst.

Does anyone can tell me what is wrong in the code?

Comment: If the executable can't be run by the IDE, and turning off your AV software makes the problem go away, your AV software is probably deleting it as soon as it's created. Create an exception (exclusion) for your development directory in your AV software. You do have a serious problem in your code, however. What do you expect `probando_1` to return if it's called with something other than `a` or `b`? Turn on hints and warnings in your project compiler options, and **pay attention** to the hints and warnings the compiler gives you - they're there for a reason.

Comment: Didn't we answer the same question from you a couple of days ago? Your AV software deletes your compiled file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the executable can't be run by the IDE, and turning off your AV software makes the problem go away, your AV software is probably deleting it as soon as it's created. Create an exception (exclusion) for your development directory in your AV software.

You do have a serious problem in your code, however. What do you expect `probando_1` to return if it's called with something other than `a` or `b`? It's a good habit to always initialize the result of a function:

```
function probando_1(url, parte: string): string;
begin
  Result := 'nothing';  { or Result := ''; }
  if (parte = 'a') then
  begin
    Result := 'test';
  end;
  if (parte = 'b') then
  begin
    Result := 'test';
  end;
end;
```

Comment: thanks for the help Ken White, but the error persists I found an alternative way of doing what I wanted, I have to admit I'm starting to hate avast.

Comment: Jose, send them your executable and report your problem as a false positive. However, I don't believe that a code like you've shown would make Avast think it's a virus (it's not that crappy AV). More I would suspect you have a virus (which modifies your just compiled binary) on your machine.